# (proof hint) Closure of Set is Closed.

Tags: general-topology

I would like to prove that "closure of set is closed set again".

closure of set A means intersection of all closed set that contains A, but it looks there's some possibility for this intersection to be open.

where to start? or what kind of property do I have to concentrate on?

Comment: Try proving intersection of any collection of closed sets is closed. Do you know how to prove union of any collection of open set is open?

Comment: An arbitrary intersection of closed sets is closed by definition. What leads you to believe that it could be open?

Comment: "but it looks there's some possibility for this intersection to be open" Please elaborate on your concerns. It feels like your real question is hiding in there.

Comment: @LiChunMin by the definition of a topology, the union of open sets is open

Comment: @AydinOzbek I don't know what def is he using…perhaps he is only working in metric space.

Comment: It could be open. But open does **not** imply "not closed"! Sets are not doors...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma awesome expression..

Comment: @delog It's something my teacher said during metric topology class. It's a common misconception that he wanted to root out.

Comment: @delog there is even a type of topological space called a "door space" where any subset is open or closed (or both, like $\emptyset$ and $X$ always are).

Answer (score 1):

For a general metric space, start by showing that arbitrary union of open sets are open. If you are using a general topology, then you already have this covered! Then use De Morgan's law to show that arbitrary intersection of closed sets is closed.

Can you take it from here?